# SQLAlchemy create_all without flask

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a model being used by my flask server as well as a command-line tool. I want both the script and flask app to be able to create tables programmatically using this model.

In the flask app, I do this:

```
from models import db
db.app = app
db.init_app(app)
db.create_all()
```

However I can't use this code in the command-line tool as there is no 'app', and without the app I get

> RuntimeError: application not registered on db instance and no application bound to current context

Which makes sense. So how do I make it work with the command-line tool without creating another version of my model file?

My model file (roughly):

```
class User(db.Model):
__tablename__ = "users"

id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
account_id = Column(BigInteger, nullable=False)
team_name = Column(String, nullable=False)
external_id = Column(String(36), nullable=False)
# should not be filled with web app, but for misc notes we take later
notes = Column(String)


def __str__(self):
    return "User (account_id={}, team_name='{}', external_id='{}')".format(
            self.account_id, self.team_name, self.external_id)


__table_args__ = (
    UniqueConstraint("account_id", name="unique_account_id"),
    UniqueConstraint("external_id", name="unique_external_id"),
    UniqueConstraint("team_name", name="unique_team_name")
)
```

Comment: You don't need to forgo the `flask` object in your command-line tool unless that's a hard requirement. All you need to do is to wrap your command-line's `main` with [`with app.app_context()`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/appcontext/#creating-an-application-context).